# Adapter to connect Intel Compute Stick to Mac to see the output

Tags: hdmi, thunderbolt, osx, micro-pc, video-adapters

I have Intel Compute Stick which has HDMI male connector as output which I would like to connect to Macbook Pro which has HDMI port (female), USB and ThunderBolt Mini DisplayPort. My goal is to see the screen of the device on my laptop screen.

I've tried to connect the device to MBP HDMI port, but it doesn't work, so I assume I need to purchase some converter.

What I need to have in order to capture display output from the stick device?

Would ThunderBolt to HDMI adapter cable would work in that case, or some kind of [virtual webcam](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/631/15) or anything else? I've no budget limits (just reasonable price to quality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to connect the Intel Compute Stick to something that you can view the output of the device, correct?

First off, you cannot connect it into the HDMI port of your MacBook Pro.  That's output only.  That's like trying to connect the HDMI out port on a DVD player to the HDMI port on a game console - it's not going to work.

What you need is a monitor with an HDMI port as an input.  Any monitor with an HDMI port will work.

If you want to capture the video, you need a video capture device.  The [Elgato Gaming Video Capture](https://www.elgato.com/en/gaming) products have been really good.